# Acces list element above current list in list of lists c#

Tags: c#, list, iteration

I am trying to acces an element in a list of lists. I am looping through the lists as seen in code below and would have thought to be able put - 1 or + 1 at the list the same as it is possible with the elements in the lists however this doesn't seem to work or my syntax is wrong. I wrote a comment in CAPS where the problem is situated.
Code below `

```
foreach (var list in Speelveld)
            {
                for (var element = 0; element < Speelveld.Count(); element++)
                {
                    if (list[element] != list[5])
                    {
                        if (list[element].GetType() == typeof(Herbivoor) && list[element + 1].GetType() == typeof(LeegOrganisme))
                        {

                            intStap = r.Next(4);
                            Console.WriteLine("Rechts leeg");
                            //Controleer of het te checken item niet het als eerste in de lijst staat

                            if(list[element] != list[0]){
                            //check range waarin de herbivoor zich kan voortbewegen

                                if(list[element - 1].GetType() == typeof(LeegOrganisme))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Links leeg");
                                    links = true;
                                }
                                //HERE I AM TRYING TO ACCES THE LIST ABOVE THE CURRENT LIST, I am looking for an alternative syntax to the list - 1[element]
                                if(list - 1[element].GetType() == typeof(LeegOrganisme))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Boven leeg");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
```

Comment: The inner list doesn't have a reference to it's parent "container", so it really isn't possible to do it that way. You could create a new type that holds that reference.

Comment: Ok thx i'll look into that :)

Comment: At first glance this code makes no sense. Why would the for loop upper bound of “list” be the count of “Speelveld”?

Comment: If you want to access the previous or the following list I suggest you drop the foreach and use just two for loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your foreach loop  `foreach (var list in Speelveld)` to a for loop `for (int i = 0; i < SpeelveId.Count(); i++)` then you could later access an item in `SpeelveId` via index.

I'm making the assumption that the second for loop's upper bound you were previously using, `SpleeveId.Count` is wrong, and you want to use the upper bound of the current list. I've made a change to reflect that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Speelveld.Count; i++)
{
    for (var element = 0; element < Speelveld[i].Count; element++)
    {
        if (Speelveld[i][element] != Speelveld[i][5])
        {
            if (Speelveld[i][element].GetType() == typeof(Herbivoor) && Speelveld[i][element + 1].GetType() == typeof(LeegOrganisme))
            {

                intStap = r.Next(4);
                Console.WriteLine("Rechts leeg");
                //Controleer of het te checken item niet het als eerste in de lijst staat

                 if(Speelveld[i][element] != Speelveld[i][0])
                 {
                 //check range waarin de herbivoor zich kan voortbewegen

                     if(Speelveld[i][element - 1].GetType() == typeof(LeegOrganisme))
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Links leeg");
                         links = true;
                     }

                     if(Speelveld[i-1][element].GetType() == typeof(LeegOrganisme))
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Boven leeg");
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that each sublist has the same amount of elements as the parent list?